# How to customize splash screen in pwa?

Tags: javascript, json, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, manifest

I have two icons.
Ex:- icon-I , icon-II

I want to customize PWA splash screen. On launching time show icon-II but home screen icon show icon-I

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Demo School",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": [
              {
                 "src": "images/icon-I-72x72.png",
                 "type" : "image/png",
                 "sizes" : "72x72"
               },
               {
                 "src": "images/icon-I-96x96.png",
                 "type" : "image/png",
                 "sizes" : "96x96"
               },
               {
                 "src": "images/icon-I-128x128.png",
                 "type" : "image/png",
                 "sizes" : "128x128"
               }, 
               {
                 "src": "images/icon-I-144x144.png",
                 "type" : "image/png",
                 "sizes" : "144x144"
               },
               {
                 "src": "images/icon-I-152x152.png",
                 "type" : "image/png",
                 "sizes" : "152x152"
               },
               {
                 "src": "images/icon-I-192x192.png",
                 "type" : "image/png",
                 "sizes" : "192x192"
               },
               {
                 "src": "images/icon-I-384x384.png",
                 "type" : "image/png",
                 "sizes" : "384x384"
               },
               {
                 "src": "images/icon-I-152x152.png",
                 "type" : "image/png",
                 "sizes" : "512x512"
               }
  ],
  "short_name" : "D.S",
  "start_url" : "./",
  "display" : "standalone",
  "background_color" : "#FFE9D2",
  "theme_color" : "#FFE1C4",
  "orientation" : "portrait-primary"
}
```

In the PWA, on launching page I want to show icon-II

[Icon-II on launching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHQn1.png)

but on home screen icon I want to show icon-I.

[Icon-I in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7F7N.jpg) 
[Icon-I](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6cAc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

splash_screens:[
{
"src": "images/icon-I-96x96.png",
type": "image/png",
sizes": "96x96"
}
]